Is it possible to access a parameter of a function from another function in C?
Is it possible to access the value of a variable from a function within another function. You can assume that the first function is called in the main one.
Here is an example:
int foo (int x) {
    int z;
    // Do things...
    return 0;
}

int bar () {
    // Access value of z here.
    // Do more things...
    return 0;
}


It is impossible and moreover does not make sense.

The blessed way is to pass the address of the same variable to both functions. An other possible way is to use a global variable. Global and static variables used to be common in the good old days, but they do not support threading...

Potentially relevant reading: What is the XY problem?

@SergeBallesta "Global and static variables .... do not support threading" - I've never heard that before. What makes them different from other variables shared between threads?

What makes you think there is a z to access when you call bar? Once foo exits, the lifetime of z is over. Then there is no z and no value to access. And z is not "a parameter of a function".

Perhaps you can use blocks (a language extension available on Macs I guess)

@TedLyngmo Technically you can use global variables in a multithreaded program, but it's usually a pretty bad idea.

The title of your question does not correspond to the body of your question. In the title, you ask about accessing a "parameter" of a function from another function, but in the question body, you ask about accessing a non-parameter local variable from another function. Please [edit] the question to fix this contradiction.

@CharlesSrstka, using global variables is exceedingly common in multithreaded programs.  Synchronization objects such as mutexes and condition variables are often declared globally.  Shared data on which multiple threads operate, likewise.  That's not the only way to do it, but "usually a pretty bad idea" seems a relatively controversial assertion.

Does the function foo call the function bar, so that you have both functions running at the same time? If not, then your question does not make sense, because the variable z won't even exist when the function bar is running. Maybe the question you want to ask is how to make the variable z continue existing after the function foo returns? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, and your question will likely be reopened.

@JohnBollinger: I know that global and static do have common usage including in multithreaded programs. What I meant is that they require special synchronization because the different threads will access the same variable and beginners can easily fall in various caveats with them.

@SergeBallesta, I understood what you meant, though I wish you had phrased it more clearly for the benefit of those with less experience. Possibly including Charles, to whose remarks my previous comment was directed.

@JohnBollinger In the 1980s, it used to be fairly common for us to use global variables all over the place; in the 21st century, it is generally frowned upon, for a number of very valid reasons. Yes, you can protect a global with a mutex, but there are better, and less brittle ways to organize your application's data. I certainly would not make a habit of recommending their use to inexperienced developers.

"they require special synchronization because the different threads will access the same variable" - You need synchronization for all variables shared between threads so how is the synchronization needed for globals special?

@TedLyngmo: Automatic variables are not shared so need no special processing. I thought about the difference between for example strtok which internally uses a static variable and strtok_r which uses a user provided pointer to maintain its state...

@SergeBallesta Automatic variables are usually shared by passing pointers to them to the thread start functions and all acceses to these automatic variables need the same synchronization that is required for globals. The point of the _r familiy is to not work on shared data, so it's not relevant here.

Outside of foo its (non-static) local variables don't exist. That's the whole point of it being a local variable.
If you need to communicate state between functions you have two basic methods:
Global variables
int z = 4;

void foo(int x) {
    z = z + x;
}

void bar(void) {
    z = z * 2;
}

int main(void) {
    foo(6);
    bar();

    printf("%d\n", z);
    // prints 20
}

Avoid this whenever possible. It makes debugging substantially harder because functions cannot be tested without considering what every other function might be doing to the state of that global variable.
Via function arguments and return values
Much better is to pass information via a function's arguments and return values. For small data types and simple manipulations, it's probably best practice to pass variables by value and return an updated value from the function.
For larger data types where copying would be inefficient, or where multiple arguments need to be updated, you can pass a pointer to another value and use that to update the value it points to.
An example of passing a pointer:
void foo(int *z, int x) {
    *z = *z + x;
}

void bar(int *z) {
    *z = *z * 2;
}

int main(void) {
    int z = 4;
    foo(&z, 6);
    bar(&z);

    printf("%d\n", z);
    // prints 20
}


Yes you can if this variable is static.
int *foo(int x)
{
   static int z;
   
   /* do stuff */

   return &z
}

then knowing the reference of z you can safely access it.
